# Voltage divider to measure battery voltage on Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage-divider

I am working on a 3V battery powered arduino project. I need to monitor the battery so that I could send a signal when battery is dying. At first it seemed tricky because the same voltage is being used by the micro-controller but later on I came to know that there is some sort of internal 1.1V reference in Arduino. However I need to use a voltage divider to reduce the voltage. This is the circuit described on the [webpage](https://maniacbug.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/sensor-node/):

[image]

PIN_A1 is where the battery voltage is being read. High value resistors have been used to avoid excessive current draw.

My question is - What is the aim of using a voltage divider here?

EDIT:

It has been figured out that voltage divider is bringing the battery voltage within internal voltage reference range i.e. 1.1 V.

(Credit goes to Vladimir)

Comment: 3V*470kohm/1470kohm=.959V < 1.1V that's why

Comment: Not answering your question, but... [there's a way of measuring Vcc without using any external circuit at all](http://provideyourown.com/2012/secret-arduino-voltmeter-measure-battery-voltage/)

Comment: @Vladimir - Now I see the blunder I made. :(

Comment: Do read the link above - you can just configure the ADC so it uses Vcc as reference, and measures the 1.1 V internal reference as the signal. This achieves the same thing but without any resistors, leakage, etc.

Comment: Great link @tomnexus you never stop to learn.

Comment: @tomnexus I disagree - that is an answer to the question, since the ultimate question is "how do I measure battery voltage from an AVR".

Comment: As a side note, don't use ground but instead tie that to an output. Drive it low, take the measurement, then drive it high again. And I'd use much smaller value resistors, to actually place a load on the battery for the split second it is measured.

Comment: @rdtsc - That's a great idea. However I have a concern. I will be keeping the micro-controller in sleep condition for most of the time. Do you think that output pin will stay HIGH once the uC goes to sleep?

Comment: The pin likely would go to a high-impedance state. Whether it's driven logic high or "open", both should cause negligible current flow. (The proper way to do this on a PIC microcontroller is to set it logic low, then toggle it from an input (high impedance) to an output (logic low) and back.)